# Changing text depending on date using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to switch text  depending on dates.

```html
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) == '2021-12-05' ? 'A' : 'B';
```

But I don’t want to update the text after this day, for example, if today is '2021-12-05', the text will show 'A' until forever, test B will be displayed before '2021-12-05' . Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: You need to call new Date() to load the current datetime

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = new Date() > new Date('2021-12-05') ? 'A' : 'B';
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks you for your help and advise,I forgot it can be done like this.